# How to optimize all my apps in “Battery Optimization”?

Tags: battery, xiaomi, optimization

I have xiaomi mi max 32gb -Multirom 8.4.26
I make all my apps "battery optimized" except these apps: (Greenify+amplify+powernap+Launcher+Appops+Magisk+ Xposed).
[image]

But after rebooting my mobile, apps returns non-optimized. So I need to make all my apps optimized after every reboot. This task is tiring and wastes my time.

**My Question:** Can you help me batch optimize all apps after every reboot, please? By using tasker or terminal commands or adb commands or mod or anything
Please help me

Comment: up...............................up.............................up